# FULLTEXT Relevance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm learning to set up searches in PHP with MySQL, and I like the idea of FULLTEXT BOOLEAN searches. But there's one part I'm not really sure I understand: Relevance.

According to the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html), when a word has **no** operator (plus or minus) before it, "the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher". But according to an earlier statement on that page, "They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance".

So my question is, if they don't do it automatically, how do you **manually** do it? Or at least, how does one **reference** this "Relevance"? And if you cannot, then what is the point of them assigning values if the results are not sorted by them?

Just trying to wrap my head around this whole system of BOOLEAN MODE.

Comment: If your application were newspaper or something time related you'd probably want to `order by` the date. You can get the returned score and order by it, put it in the `order by`.

Comment: See the example under **Relevancy Ranking for a Single Word Search** where it does `ORDER BY score DESC`

Comment: @Barmar: Wow...I cannot believe it. If I had just kept on reading... I only stopped to ask questions because I didn't understand so much of it and didn't want to dig the hole deeper before I understood what was there in the first half. Thank you :)

Comment: Let me ask one more thing: In the examples shown, it has the MATCH and AGAINST arguments BEFORE the FROM option. but that allows for there to be results with a score of 0. Is it possible to use the MATCH and AGAINST after the FROM as well, to avoid results with neither word in them, or is it one or the other, either before or after?

Comment: Yes, it's common to use it in `WHERE` to just get the matching rows